# $E[X]=1.8$, where $X$ is the total number of successes of 3 trials. What is the largest/smallest $P\{X=3\}$ can be?

Tags: probability, expectation

[image]

Since each trial has the same probability of success, $p$, can you not uniquely solve for $p$? I.e:

Let, $X_{i} = 1$ if the $i^{th}$ trial is a success ($0$ otherwise). Then, $X=\sum_{i=1}^{3}X_{i}$, and $E[X]  = E[\sum_{i=1}^{3}X_{i}] = \sum_{i=1}^{3}E[X_{i}] = \sum_{i=1}^{3}p =3p =1.8$

So, $p=0.6$, and $P\{X=3\}=0.6^{3}$

I thought what I did was sound, but the textbook says the answer to (a) is $0.6$ and (b) is $0$.

Their reasoning (for (a)) is as follows:

[image]

However, how can the above be true if all three trials have the same probability of success? That is, how can $P\{X=1\}$ and $P\{X=2\}$ be zero, when $P\{X=3\}$ is nonzero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Nothing in the problem said that the trials are **independent.**

Comment: But if they all have the same probability of success, wouldn't that make the trials independent? That is, you cannot have the situation: 2nd and 3rd trial is a success if and only if the 1st trial is a success (which is the situation you would need for $P(X=3)$ to be nonzero while $P(X=1)$ and $P(X=2)$ are zero), because then the probability of success for the 1st trial, and the probability of success for the 2nd and 3rd trial are different, no?

Comment: Here is an example, though not with probability $0.6$. We have an urn, $2$ green balls, $1$ red. We remove them one at a time, without replacement. Success on any trial is getting a green. For any $i$, the probability of success on the $i$-th trial is $\frac{2}{3}$, but the probability of $3$ successes is $0$.

Comment: Great example, I see your point now. Thanks for clearing up this conceptual issue I was having!

Comment: You are welcome. It was a bit of a trick question, we are so accustomed to iid. But there are plenty of real-life non iid situations.

Comment: In part b) when probability of X=3 is Zero , what will be will be the values for P(X=0), P(X=1) and P(X=2).

Answer (score 0):

An example to show that each trial with the same probability of success is not independent:
$U\sim Uni(0,1)$

- First trial: $U\leq 0.6$
- Second trial: $U\geq 0.4$
- Third trial: $U\leq 0.3 \text{ or }U\geq 0.6$

Obviously, they have the same $p=0.6$, but they cannot be achieved at the same time-- if 1st and 2nd trial are obtained, 3rd trial cannot succeed. The smallest possible value for $Pr\{X=3\}$ is $0$.