# Confusion about overlapping of events

Tags: probability, independence

It is Question 47 on page 85 from Ross's book(Introduction to Probability Models)

The same question at 
[$E[X]=1.8$, where $X$ is the total number of successes of 3 trials. What is the largest/smallest $P\{X=3\}$ can be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557475/ex-1-8-where-x-is-the-total-number-of-successes-of-3-trials-what-is-the)

Consider three trials, each of which is either a success or not. Let X denote the number of successes. Suppose that E[x] = 1.8.

(a) What is the largest possible value of P{X = 3}

(b) What is the smallest possible value of P{X = 3}

Since

$E[X]= E[X_1] +E[X_2] +E[X_3]$ = P{$X_1$ = 1} + P{$X_2$ =1} + P{$X_3$ =1} = 1.8

then I am stuck here

The Solution says:

**P{X=3} = P{$X_1$ = 1}** = 0.6 when $X_1 = X_2 = X_3$

But Why?

With the constraint E[x] = 1.8, the max value for them to overlap is 0.6 when $X_1 = X_2 = X_3$. (I am not sure "**overlap**" is a proper word here.)

1. What does it mean by $X_1 = X_2 = X_3$? the same distribution?
2. What is the relationship between event P{X=3} and P{X1 = 1}? Is that possible to formulate it in terms of Set Theory?

**Update 1**

3. Since whether 3 events are independent or not is not certain ,what kind of ideas behind P{X=3} = P{$X_1$ = 1}? My blind guess is overlapping?

Thanks in advance

**Update 2 **(as explained by Graham):

When three events are fully dependent, that is $X1=X2=X3$,

then $E[X]$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{3} ip(i)$ = 3 * P{X=3}

finally P{X=3} = $E[X]/3$ = 0.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does it mean by  $X_1=X_2=X_3$? the same distribution?

$X_i$ is the indicator for success in trial $\#i$.   That is $X_i=1$ if trial $\#i$ is a success and $X_i=0$ if it is a failure.   These are Bernoulli random variables.

Hence $X_1=X_2=X_3$ means that the trials are *fully dependent*; they are either all successes or all failure.   That is, if one trial is a success then all are, and otherwise they are all failures.

> What is the relationship between event $\{X=3\}$ and $\{X_1 = 1\}$? Is that possible to formulate it in terms of Set Theory?

The count for successes in three trials is the sum of the three indicators.   $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$

$\{X=3\}$ is the event $\{X_1=1\}\cap \{X_2=1\}\cap\{X_3=1\}$... that, is the event that all three trials are a success.   This also may be written: $\{X_1=X_2=X_3=1\}$.

And if the trials are fully dependent, then $\{X=3\}=\{X_1=1\}$ ... all three trials will be a success if the first is so.

Comment: Thanks for kind explanation. What kind of ideas behind P{X=3} = P{X1X1 = 1}. Dependent means of overlapping, right ?