# Largest possible value of a probability

Tags: probability

Let's suppose we have $3$ trials each with same probability of success. Let $X$ denote the total number of successes in these trials and put $E(X) = 1.8$. Find the largest and smallest value of $P(X=3)$.

#### Try

Let $X_i$ be $1$ is trial $i$ is success and $0$ otherwise. We have $X=X_1+X_2+X_3$. Also, $P(X_1=1)=P(X_2=1)=P(X_3=1)=p$, is given. Also,

$$ 1.8 = E(X) = P(X=1) + 2 P(X=2) + 3 P(X=3) $$

notice $X=1$ only when one $X_i=1$. Thus, $P(X=3) = 3 P(X_i=1) = 3p$ and $P(X=2)$ when any two of $X_i=1$ that is $P(X=2) = 3p^2$. Thus,

$$ 1.8 = 3p + 6p^2 + 3P(X=3) $$

$$ P(X=3) = 1.8-p-2p^2 $$

take derivative with respect to $p$ gives

$$ (P(X=3))' = -1 - 4p $$

which means the maximum have to be at $p<0$ which makes no sense. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$E[X]=1.8$, where $X$ is the total number of successes of 3 trials. What is the largest/smallest $P\{X=3\}$ can be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557475/ex-1-8-where-x-is-the-total-number-of-successes-of-3-trials-what-is-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your trials are independent

$P(X=3)= 0.6^3$

But, supposing you are biopsying some diseased tissue.  There is a probability $p$ chance that the tissue has disease, and there is some probability $q$, that any sample will show disease if the tissue is diseased.

All of the trials have equal likelihood of showing disease, but they are not independent.

If $q$ is big... i.e. let $q = 1$

Either all three samples show disease or none do.

$P(X=3) = 0.6$

At the other extreme we can set up scenarios where at least one sample will always positive, but it is impossible for a 3 to be positive.

$P(X=3) = 0$